# Remove duplicates in a String [] list f#

Tags: arrays, list, f#, duplicates

I need some noob help...

I have a `String[] list` (a list that each element is a Array of strings)

I wish to remove all duplicates in the list. But to see if they are duplicates I need to see the fist element in the array.

what I have tried is

```
let NotDuplicated =
Duplicated.[0]
|> Seq.distinct


let NotDuplicated =
Duplicated
|> Seq.distinctBy id
```

but nothing is working... can you guys please help me.. thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let NotDuplicated =
    Duplicated
    |> Seq.distinctBy (fun a -> a.[0])
```

Comment: yeah thats correct, my error was that I was missing |> Seq.toList